# Cant parse the data on GET parameter on a URL wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Url : https://example.com/testing-tweet?somevar=testData

I want to get the somevar value on the url using $_GET.

```
print_r($_GET);
```

But It always return an empty array. Since the site is build with wordpress, I also tried the get_query_var of wordpress.

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "somevar";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

And on the page.php or custom page template.

```
var_dump(get_query_var( 'somevar' ));
```

It return empty string. I also tried to disable all the plugin on the site and remove all the custom query var that is existing but still no luck any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What if you try without the speech marks around `testData` in you URL?

Comment: I try both `$_GET` and `get_query_var('somevar')` in single post and single page and I can get the value. Try it in a default theme

Comment: @thebluefox Thank you for your comment, I tried it but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryan AW yeh I tried it on the default theme of wordpress the 2017 it works fine.

Comment: Maybe the problem is on our custom theme, but its kinda-weird because I already disabled all plugin and custom hooks still not working.